# Openshift Origin OKD bugfixing and patching

Tags: openshift, okd

As OCP docs says: "Security, bug fix, and enhancement updates for OpenShift Container Platform 3.11 are released as asynchronous errata through the Red Hat Network." Are these also available for OKD 3.11? Is there any way to apply present bug fixes and patches to running OKD cluster like for OCP? As I saw docker hub origin images are not so frequently updated so probably latest patches are not included there. Any of you are running OKD cluster? Do you patch it? Bear in mind I do not ask about upgrades (for example from 3.10 to 3.11) but only about updates for the given version.